# Connecting Node.js to Notepad++ Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, notepad++, nppexec

I'm trying to get the node console integrated into Notepad++ with the NppExec plugin following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCOPaT0kriw) as a reference (I know it's bad, but there are no other useful tutorials like it).

At around 22 seconds, he opens the plugin's "Execute..." command box and puts in his stuff, but the drop down menu has node included for him, but not for me. It's not on the list, even though node.js is installed.

I tried moving the node directory into the same directory as the notepad++ installation, that didn't work. I'm not sure how to continue. It seems everyone else is using atom to work with, but i'd like to stick with what i'm familiar with.

Comment: Hey pal! I strongly recomend you to use some of the most used IDE (Integrated  Developement Enviroment) as your code editor.
You could try Atom, or VSCode.
They are optimized for the task that you are trying to do, and they come with a lot of adventages like debuggers, pluguins, the posibility of work with several integrated terminals and a lot of built in features.
In fact, they also have a realy good and active comunity, so you will never feel lonely and desoriented.
I will leave this link if you want to look for another code editor :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF3dd2f7eDg

Comment: I checked the comments on the tutorial that you are following and found this:

>.node_reply_history must be saved in the root-folder from notepad++-. If then Node (assiciated script) is still missing, you could just create it under "save..." by giving the command "cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY
node $(FILE_NAME)" the name "Node".

Comment: Also, in the documentation:

There is Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute... window that allows to execute NppExec's scripts (set of commands).
NppExec's commands and variables are listed in the "NppExec.txt" file.
To get more details, type "help" (without the quotes) directly in NppExec's Console. To get a detailed help about any NppExec's command, type "help [command]" - e.g. "help npp_open" or "help set". And don't forget about Plugins -> NppExec -> Help/Manual.

https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec

Answer (score 0):

His tutorial helped me a lot - thanks!
His video had node there because he had previously saved it but everyone else needs to create it! In that window you simply need to type in the commands he has there:

```
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
node $(FILE_NAME)
```

then press save and name it node, after which it will appear in that select box.
You never actually need to select it from the select box unless you wish to edit it in the future - just continue with the rest of the tutorial.